# python Incorrect date when converting unix time to utc time

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, unix

i would like to convert unix timestamp to utc time. i have to convert it using the code below, but each time i get an incorrect result. online date converter returns correct result. how to convert a date to count the number of hours between two periods?

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1633438809404))
ValueError: year 53731 is out of range


import time

epoch = 1633438809404
time_obj = time.localtime(int(epoch))
print(time_obj)

time.struct_time(tm_year=53731, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=18, tm_min=36, tm_sec=44, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=225, tm_isdst=0)


import pandas

timestamp = 1633438809404
unix_conversion=pandas.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='ns')
print(str(unix_conversion))

1970-01-01 00:27:13.438809404
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp you've provided (`1633438809404`) is a timestamp *in milliseconds*, yes?  If so, then divide it by 1000 before providing it to `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` (which expects a timestamp in seconds):

```py
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1633438809404/1000)
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 5, 9, 0, 9, 404000)
```

or, when using `pandas.to_datetime`, ensure you use `unit='ms'`:

```py
>>> timestamp = 1633438809404
>>> unix_conversion=pandas.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='ms')
>>> unix_conversion
Timestamp('2021-10-05 13:00:09.404000')
```

Comment: `fromtimestamp` takes an argument `tz`, so if the OP expects UTC, you should set that to `datetime.timezone.utc`. Same goes for `pd.to_datetime`, here you can set `utc=True`.